# Using methods of one DAO into another

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, design-patterns, architecture

I have 3 Service classes in my application each written for specific functionalities with respective DAO interfaces & their implementation classes.
All services have different packages.

Say I have

`AService.java & ADAO.java`   ADAO interface is injected into AService.java class. Similarly I have

```
BService.java & BDAO.java

CService.java & CDAO.java
```

Now I want to refer some methods of BDAO & CDAO implementation classes in AService.java

What should be the best way to do that?

1. I inject BDAO & CDAO in AService.java. Would that be a good practice? Services are tightly coupled in this scenario.
2. I write the redundant code in respective DAOs.
3. I create a generic DAO & try to extract all the common methods from all the individual DAOs & put into that. This is an extensive task. Also I am not sure in future which method of which DAO will be required in which particular service.

Comment: You should do 1. It's perfectly normal for a functional service to have to access data from various entities, and thus use several DAOs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go by the first option in this case. A service can be of a higher level of abstraction than the DAOs.

For sure i wouldn't go by the second approach, the third option could be valid if the common code is some utility code, i wouldn't do this if the common code is from different entities/logical domain.

Comment: I don't agree with suggesting the first option. It is not a good Idea to inject DAOs from other Domains and bypass their business logic layer. Or would you do the same in a controller, - I guess not?

Answer (score 5):

If you share behaviour in the DAO layer you should do it with inheritance or composition(Association) inside the DAO layer.

You sliced your application by Domains like "A", "B", "C", so the `AService` should **not** by pass the `BService` to access any kind of B's logic implemented in the B-Domain.

See [@oliver-gierke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18122/) talk ["Whoops! Where did my architecture go?"](https://speakerdeck.com/olivergierke/whoops-where-did-my-architecture-go-2?slide=10). Because of this easy Bypassing he proposes to organize packages like this

```
public      class com.product.a.AService
/*package*/ class com.product.a.ADao

public      class com.product.b.BService
/*package*/ class com.product.b.BDao

public      class com.product.c.CService
/*package*/ class com.product.c.CDao
```

With this you enforced that no other "Domain" is using the Daos of your Domain. Otherwise you can violate your Architecture rules.

The problem with sharing DAOs of different domains, is that you may bypass businesslogic implemented in the other domains service layer.
For example, with every "delete" operation on `B` a email should be send to a customer. In case the `AService` uses the `BRepository` directly, it grants access to delete a B instance and bypass the logic to send an email.

Comment: Making a "common" DAO class with "common functionalities" that might be extended if needed by other DAOs worked lovely for me. Thanks.